# Is this use of realloc correct?

Tags: c, realloc, alloc

**Original question**

Can I use `realloc()` function like the following code:

```
int *ptr, i, num=5;

for (i=0; i<num; i++)
  void *nptr = realloc (ptr, (i+1) * sizeof(int) );
```

Comment: No. Once the original pointer is used in a realloc, only the return value is (hopefully) usable for the next iteration. (and your original pointer isn't initialized; another trip into undefined behavior). It also leaks memory like a sieve. Oddly, initializing `ptr` to NULL would remove the UB, but you would still have the leak.

Comment: `ptr` is not initialize.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no, you should initialize `ptr` at the beginning and then assign the new value

```
int *ptr = 0;

for (unsigned i=0; i<5; i++) {
  void *nptr = realloc (ptr, (i+1) * sizeof(int) );
  if (nptr) ptr = nptr;
  else abort();
}
```

Otherwise at the first call you could pass some random value to `realloc`. And the memory that you allocate in subsequent calls would simply be lost.

Answer (score -1):

No, You should initialize  pointer `ptr` and `nptr` with NULL. And declare nptr before for loop. 
your code should be like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
        int *ptr=NULL, i, num=5;
        void *nptr=NULL;
        for (i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
                nptr = realloc (ptr, (i+1) * sizeof(int) );
                if (NULL != nptr)
                    ptr = nptr;
        }
}
```

Comment: @Abhiteshkhatri In the loop, every time `ptr` is `NULL`. In case that `ptr` is a null pointer, the function behaves like malloc, assigning a new block of size bytes and returning a pointer to its beginning.